# Паралельное исполнение функции в php

Tags: php

Интересует как запустить выполнения функции паралельно внутри другой функции. Если я захожу на ссылку *site.com/action/?from=0&to500* то сайт запускает функцию которая запускает другую функцию. Сама функция парсит страницы. Так как страницы долго грузить то за одно выполнение скрипта получаеться парсить только 500 страниц. Но если я запущу данную ссылку с изменением from-to на другие параметры в 20 вкладках. То все вместе парсит быстро. То-есть скрипт запускаетсья паралелньо. Как можно симулировать в PHP такой же процесс внутри кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов несколько, самый правильный: погуглить в сторону асинхронного выполнения.

Второй вариант, посмотреть свой парсер, возможно его можно переделать.

Третий вариант, скорей костыльный, но вы можете получать `?from=0&to500` разбивать его на несколько частей, например если на 2, то: `?from=0&to250` и `?from=251&to500` и запросить эти пути без времени ожидания.

И запустить 2 курла (а лучше используя [multi_curl](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-init.php)), с параметрами без ожидания, типа такого:

```
$URL = 'http://site.com/action/?from=0&to250';
$CURL= curl_init();
curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 100);
curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 100);
curl_exec($CURL);
curl_close($CURL);
```

и так-же для второй ссылки, если много и динамически, значит циклом запускаем (а еще лучше юзать [multi_curl](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-init.php))

Answer (score 1):

Простейший это использовать вызов с помощью большого количества запросов, грубо говоря на самого себя делать какое-то N раз запрос в котором парситься следующая часть страницы.

Можно посмотреть в сторону многопоточности в виде `pThreads` Что позволит одним скриптом выполнять большее количество раз парсинг параллельно и именно по настоящему параллельно. [`pThreads`](https://m.habr.com/post/300952/).

Ну а можно использовать асинхронное программирования которое на мой взгляд, лучшие решения, смотрите в строну `PhpReact`.